# Delegate backend to ask to only one instance?

Tags: docker, sockets, websocket, redis, containers

I'm creating an application that involves a frontend that communicates with a backend using Websockets.

I want the application to be scalable and be able to handle failover, so I'm assuming that there will be multiple backend container instances and will be using Redis channels to make sure that every instance can access the same data.

My concern is that there are certain operations that need to happen in the backend that it will then update Redis about - but how do I ensure that only one of my backend instances carries out this logic? I don't want errors to be caused by multiple instances trying to write to the same redis key value pair at the same time and I don't want to duplicate functionality for my users.

The idea is a voting application and the idea is that when either all votes are cast or the timer is complete my Flask backend will tally the votes and trigger the next round of voting. The issue is I don't want multiple instances to trigger the next round as I worry it could cause conflicts.

Any thoughts? Please let me know if this didn't make any sense.

Comment: This is a very broad issue and there are multiple ways to handle it depending on how your operations are triggered. If you are using cron jobs, for example, you might set an environment variable to enable them on a single container, or you might split the cron jobs into a separate dedicated container which is run as a single instance. In more advanced cases, you might use some sort of job queue.

Comment: @PádraigGalvin so to give full context the idea is a voting application and the idea is that when either all votes are cast or the timer is complete my Flask backend will tally the votes and trigger the next round of voting.

The issue is I don't want multiple instances to trigger the next round as I worry it could cause conflicts. I think a job queue is probably the right idea, could you point me in the right direction for what you would suggest? Thank you

Comment: @ChiefAntiphates give the full context as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71726378/edit) to your question, not in comments. Moreover please read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask), [on topic](/help/on-topic), and [creating a minimal example](/help/mcve) that you will add to you question to ground it to some real life situation.